# Correct way to override hashCode() for persistent entity containing a boolean field?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistent

```
private long configKeyMasterId;
private String configKey;
private boolean isDisplay;

public int hashCode() {
    int result = (int) (configKeyMasterId ^ (configKeyMasterId >>> 32));
    result = 31 * result + (configKey != null ? configKey.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (isDisplay != null ? isDisplay.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

This is what I have where `isDisplay` is a boolean field. I know that the 3rd line is wrong, but how do I fix it?

Is something as naive as,

```
result = 31 * result + (isDisplay != false ? Boolean.hashCode(isDisplay) : 0);
```

okay?

I don't know how or why exactly the `hashCode()` has to be overriden but I'm reading up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for `false` is redundant. Just do

```
result = 31 * result + Boolean.hashCode(isDisplay);
```

**EDIT** Note that this assumes `isDisplay` is a primitive field. If it's a boxed field (`Boolean`), the version you posted (with the null check) should be correct.

Comment: Other than that, there's nothing else to be done for this, am I right?

Comment: Also, does changing the check for `false` to a check for `true` have any effect?

Comment: @AshharHasan They'll both affect the result, but the check is unnecessary.

Comment: The would throw an NPE if isDisplay is null

Comment: @SleimanJneidi it's not declared in the source code. If you're referring to the null check, I think that's just a copy of the previous line, which OP acknowledges is wrong. If it's indeed boxed, there would be nothing wrong with OP's code.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that this approach it better as other people reading my code will find it normal instead of the newer approach in @SleimanJneidi 's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Java 7 or later versions you can use `Objects.hash(...)` rather writing your own and avoid the null check.

```
return Objects.hash(configKey, isDisplay);
```

Comment: So, why do I see most people writing the lengthy `hashCode` functions? Is there some difference I am missing?

Comment: @AshharHasan I suppose they are not aware of it

Comment: It's slightly less efficient if your fields are primitives.